# Sets of solutions of trigonometic equations

Tags: trigonometry

[image]
Here is a part of my textbook.Here sets A and B are shown equal.But $\frac{2π}{3}$ does not belongs to Set A but belongs to Set B.Then how does they both are equal?

Comment: In fact $B\subseteq A$ and $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ does not belong in $B$. It is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There is a single typographic error--a stray comma--in the statement in the book.

What is written in the book is

$$B = \left\{ \ldots, \pm \frac\pi6, \frac{2\pi}3, \pm \frac\pi6, \ldots \right\}.$$

What *should* have been written is

$$B = \left\{ \ldots, \pm \frac\pi6, \frac{2\pi}3 \pm \frac\pi6, \ldots \right\}.$$

Notice that in the book there is a comma with $\frac{2\pi}3$ on the left side of the comma and $\pm \frac\pi6$ on the right side.
That comma should not be there and in the corrected formula I have removed it.
Thus $\frac{2\pi}3$ is *not* a member of $B$;
instead, $\frac{2\pi}3 - \frac\pi6$ is a member of $B$
(by taking the $-$ sign for the $\pm$ in $\frac{2\pi}3 \pm \frac\pi6$)
and $\frac{2\pi}3 + \frac\pi6$ is a member of $B$ (by taking the $+$ sign for the $\pm$).

Notice that $\frac{2\pi}3 - \frac\pi6 = \frac\pi2$ (which is listed as an element of $A$) and $\frac{2\pi}3 + \frac\pi6 = \frac{5\pi}6$ (which also is listed as an element of $A$).

It is good to check these things to make sure they are really true!
Indeed in this case you found an error. This can happen as a book is prepared for printing.